# SQL*Plus - interactive mode on windows

Tags: oracle, windows, sqlplus

How can I issue commands through SQL*Plus on Windows?

In Linux is like this:

```
sqlplus -s /nolog<<EOF
conn username/password@database
EXECUTE some_proc;
EXIT;
EOF
```

And Windows?

Comment: That's not "interactive mode"; you're sending your commands to the SQL*Plus standard input. Please clarify your question.

Comment: I learnt that << send the commands in sequence to some command in Linux and it is called "interactive mode". Maybe I'm wrong, but what I want to say is to send commands to sql*plus on Windows in sequence or something such as mysql -e in mysql

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is a matter of Windows/batch, it is not specific to SQL*Plus.

You can do this:

```
(echo connect bp/bp@192.168.1.71/min19_o71
echo select * from dual;
echo exit
) | sqlplus -S /nolog
```

Result:

```
C:\Users\balaz>(echo connect bp/bp@192.168.1.71/min19_o71
More? echo select * from dual;
More? echo exit
More? ) | sqlplus -S /nolog

D
-
X


C:\Users\balaz>
```

Or just use a script, that method is specific to SQL*Plus:

```
C:\Users\balaz>type script.sql
connect bp/bp@192.168.1.71/min19_o71
select * from dual;
exit

C:\Users\balaz>sqlplus -S /nolog @script.sql

D
-
X


C:\Users\balaz>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I got using the first option, but only worked with one echo and the commands within the echo.

(echo "connect sys/manager as sysdba
           select * from dual;"
) | sqlplus /nolog

each command need to be in one different line!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure where you get the term "interactive" in this context, but what  you describe is known in the *nix world as "input redirection".  It is actually the *opposite* of 'interactive', where  you would simply start sqlplus and 'interact' with it via the keyboard. Unfortunately, Windows simply doesn't work that way - yet another shortcoming of Windows and another reason I avoid it every chance I get.  The way I write my windows command scripts (to avoid having to maintain a separate sql script, as @Balzas Papp describes) is as follows:

```
echo connect scott/tiger@orcl > doit.sql
echo select * from emp >> doit.sql
echo exit >> doit.sql
sqlplus /nolog @doit.sql
```

Of course, there is nothing about this that requires sqlplus to be started '/nolog', with the connect command embedded in the script. You could just as easily

```
echo select * from emp > doit.sql
echo exit >> doit.sql
sqlplus scott/tiger@orcl @doit.sql
```

Note that my first 'echo' command uses a single '>' to redirect the output to 'doit.sql'. This will cause any existing copy to 'doit.sql' to be overwritten, while the following lines use a double '>>' which indicates to append the redirected line rather than overwriting.  One could also choose to delete 'doit.sql' before starting to recreate it, then simply use '>>' for ALL of the redirection lines.  This could be seen as a better way because if you needed to edit the script at a later date you wouldn't risk mixing up where the single and double redirection indicators go.

Also note that Balzas demonstrates using EZConnect syntax while I demonstrate using traditional tns net service name, depending on tnsnames.ora.  Either is fine and has nothing specific about the technique either of us demonstrates.